# ORA-01722: invalid number in execute immediate

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am running the following script in SQL Developer but getting the below error -

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   ORA-06512: at line 85

The data passed to this query is coming from a different table.
DATA BEING PASSED -

```
BAN - 945170744, ACTV_BILL_SEQ_NO- 12 , SUBSCRIBER_NO - 1234567891, DISCOUNT_CD - NULL, PRIOD_CVRG_ND_DATE - 04-JAN-20,
```

Note - Ban is defined as NUMBER(9) in both the tables.
SCRIPT  -

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
V_HIERARCHY_ID NUMBER(10);
V_NODE_CYCLE NUMBER(2);
V_BILL_CYCLE NUMBER(2);
V_DISCOUNT_CD CHAR(9);
V_EXP_DATE DATE;
V_COUNT NUMBER(3);
v_val_Done_by varchar2(25) ;
v_ban NUMBER(9);
v_comments varchar2(20);
v_success varchar2(10) :='SUCCESS';
v_yesnoind varchar2(1) :='Y';
v_comments_1 varchar2(30) :='DISCOUNT EXPIRED';
v_comments_2 varchar2(30) :='DISCOUNT NOT FOUND';
v_issue_Desc  varchar2(50) :='NEW RECORD MISSING';

BEGIN 

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('BAN: '|| :1 || '  ACTV_BILL_SEQ_NO : ' || :2 || ' SUBSCRIBER: '|| :3 || 
'COLUMN_NAME : ' || :4|| ' COLUMN_DATA: '|| :5|| 'DIFF_DATA : ' || :6 || ' SOC: ' ||:7|| ' 
FEATURE_CODE: ' ||:8|| ' FTR_REVENUE_CODE: ' ||:9|| ' PRIOD_CVRG_ST_DATE: ' ||:10|| ' 
PRIOD_CVRG_ND_DATE: ' ||:11|| ' ACTV_REASON_CODE: ' ||:12|| 'BALANCE_IMPACT_CODE: '|| :13 || '  
SOURCE_APPL_CODE : ' || :14 || ' DISCOUNT_CD: '|| :15 || ' BILL_MEDIA : ' || :16|| 'BILL_FORMAT : ' 
|| :17 || ' PRODUCT_TYPE: ' ||:18|| ' FTR_TYPE ' ||:19 || ' VAL_ID ' ||:20 );

v_ban :=:1;
V_DISCOUNT_CD :=:15;
V_EXP_DATE :=:11;

dbms_output.put_line(V_DISCOUNT_CD);
dbms_output.put_line(V_EXP_DATE);

select 'comments_'|| :20  into v_comments from dual;
select 'val_done_by_'|| :20  into  v_val_Done_by from dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line(v_val_Done_by);
DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line(v_comments);
SELECT HIERARCHY_ID INTO V_HIERARCHY_ID FROM BILLING_ACCOUNT WHERE BAN =:1;

IF V_HIERARCHY_ID IS NULL 
THEN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT FROM BAN_DISCOUNT WHERE BAN =:1 AND TRIM(DISCOUNT_CODE) = 
V_DISCOUNT_CD AND EXPIRATION_DATE < V_EXP_DATE;

IF V_COUNT >= 1
THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE BL_DIFF_CATEGORY SET VALIDATION_STS=:2,' || v_val_Done_by || ' = :3, ' 
|| v_comments || ' = :4 WHERE BAN = :1 AND DIFF_TYPE = :5'
    using v_issue_Desc,v_comments_1,v_yesnoind,v_success,v_ban;
    COMMIT;
ELSE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE BL_DIFF_CATEGORY SET VALIDATION_STS=:2,' || v_val_Done_by || ' = :3, ' 
|| v_comments || ' = :4 WHERE BAN = :1 AND DIFF_TYPE = :5'
    using v_issue_Desc,v_comments_2,v_yesnoind,v_success,v_ban;
    COMMIT;
END IF;

ELSE

-- NODE LEVEL DISCOUNT CHECK

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT FROM CH_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES 
WHERE 
OBJ_ID IN ( SELECT ARC_FATHER_ID FROM CH_ARCS WHERE ARC_CHILD_ID = V_HIERARCHY_ID) 
AND ATTR_NAME = 'Discount Plans'
AND ATTR_VALUE = V_DISCOUNT_CD
AND VALID_TO < V_EXP_DATE;

-- BAN LEVEL DISCOUNT CHECK

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT FROM CH_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES 
WHERE 
    OBJ_ID = V_HIERARCHY_ID
    AND ATTR_NAME = 'Discount Plans'
    AND ATTR_VALUE = V_DISCOUNT_CD
    AND VALID_TO < V_EXP_DATE;

-- SUBSCRIBER LEVEL DISCOUNT CHECK

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT FROM CH_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES 
WHERE 
    OBJ_ID IN ( SELECT ARC_CHILD_ID FROM  CH_ARCS WHERE ARC_FATHER_ID = V_HIERARCHY_ID) 
    AND ATTR_NAME = 'Discount Plans'
    AND ATTR_VALUE = V_DISCOUNT_CD
    AND VALID_TO < V_EXP_DATE;

IF V_COUNT >= 1
THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE BL_DIFF_CATEGORY SET VALIDATION_STS=:2,' || v_val_Done_by || ' = :3, ' 
|| v_comments || ' = :4 WHERE BAN = :1 AND DIFF_TYPE = :5'
    using v_issue_Desc,v_comments_1,v_yesnoind,v_success,v_ban;
    COMMIT;
ELSE
    (I am facing the above error in this ELSE part in below line as it is going in this line 85)
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''UPDATE BL_DIFF_CATEGORY SET VALIDATION_STS=:2,'' || v_VAL_DONE_BY || '' = 
    :3, '' || v_comments || '' = :4 WHERE BAN = :1 AND DIFF_TYPE = :5''
    using v_issue_Desc,v_comments_2,v_yesnoind,v_success,v_ban;
    COMMIT;
END IF;

END IF;

END;
```

Comment: DISCOUNT_CD - NULL <== Null is not a valid number -- you need a coalesce here.

Comment: I think your problem is probably `WHERE ARC_FATHER_ID = V_HIERARCHY_ID`. Is `CH_ARCS.ARC_FATHER_ID` a VARCHAR2 column? Also, what types are ARC_CHILD_ID and OBJ_ID?

Comment: Where are you defining `:1` etc, as in `v_ban := :1`? How are you calling this block? If SQL Developer prompts for those (I don't have SQL Developer so I can't test), do you know that bind placeholders used in `execute immediate` are not the same as host variables populated by SQL Developer, and you actually have two sets of confusingly named variables?

Comment: In the ELSE section where you say you are having trouble, the quoting is messed up, for example `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''UPDATE BL_DIFF_CATEGORY` has two single quotes where there should be one.

Answer (score 2):

> (I am facing the above error in this ELSE part in below line as it is going in this line 85)
>      `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''UPDATE BL_DIFF_CATEGORY SET VALIDATION_STS=:2,'' || v_VAL_DONE_BY || '' =  :3, '' || v_comments || '' = :4 WHERE BAN = :1 AND DIFF_TYPE = :5''
>       using v_issue_Desc,v_comments_2,v_yesnoind,v_success,v_ban;`

There seems to be some discrepancy between orders of the placeholders in the string and the parameters in the USING clause. For instance `BAN = :1` is the **fourth** placeholder but `v_ban` is the **fifth** variable passed to the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement, whilst the value actually assigned to BAN is `v_success`.

Perhaps you simply need to review the placeholders and re-order the parameters? If so, remember to do the same for the statement in the IF branch.

Incidentally, the names of the placeholders in the string don't matter, but if you're going to use numbers you might as well put them in numeric order.

Answer (score 0):

DISCOUNT_CD - NULL <== Null is not a valid number -- you need a coalesce here

eg

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT FROM CH_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES 
WHERE 
    OBJ_ID IN ( SELECT ARC_CHILD_ID FROM  CH_ARCS WHERE ARC_FATHER_ID = V_HIERARCHY_ID) 
    AND ATTR_NAME = 'Discount Plans'
    AND ATTR_VALUE = COALESCE(V_DISCOUNT_CD,0)
    AND VALID_TO < V_EXP_DATE;
```

Comment: That's true, but it won't actually give this error message. `select 1 from dual where 1 = null` will run fine.